# Jquery: push a given set of "tr" inside a table to the very top of that table

Tags: jquery

I can't finish this Jquery script.

http://jsfiddle.net/8UDxU/

Right now what its doing is grabbing every "td" that contains an img src and a certain text and apply a css yellow background.

What i want to add to that jquery script (and i cant figure it out) is make em go to the very top of that table.

So a result all those yellow tr's would be at the very top of the table always.

Anyone can help me on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prependTo might do the trick

```
$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("$"):not(:has(img[src="images/plus.gif"]))').css("background-color", "yellow").prependTo("#SubscribersManageList tbody");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6qcX/
http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

Comment: for some reason its not working...its pushing to the top of the tables every tr that contains "$" but its not considering the .has img src...its also pushing to the top EVERY tr that contains "$" including the ones with the img

Comment: in the original link of your psoting, two appears in yellow. these two very row appear at the top of the table in my list.. cross-browser-issues?

Comment: It also appears fine for me on the jsiddle link for for soem reason when i apply it on my setup its not working fine, im executing it after doc ready

Comment: can you post a new jsfiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: yes actually the same link you posted but with jquery 1.3.2 (the only difference in the way i see it is that i dontt em all yellow like that link but that seems to be the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/h6qcX/1/

Any way to make it work on thr 1.3.2? and also how to position them right below the tr Email Address    Date Added    6.Nombre    7.Apellido    9b.Teléfono etcetc because taht tr would be the definition of each column thanks

Comment: *= seems to be fixing it in 1.3.2 http://jsfiddle.net/h6qcX/2/ it apparently has to do with ways the src attribute is compared.

Comment: thanks now its working nicely but how to position them right below the Email tr? the one where all the columns are named?

It would be right below the third row on this example

http://jsfiddle.net/h6qcX/2/

Comment: put your headers in a <thead> instead of a <tbody> :P

Comment: cant touch the code :S but i CAN tell u that tr is the only one with a class "Heading3"

Comment: @matdumsa let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2308/discussion-between-sebas-and-matdumsa)